# incompatible pointer compiler error

Tags: c

I have this assignment where we expected to write a program that takes
a positive integer number as a command line argument and prints the
smallest prime number bigger than the given number. 
The main function shouldn't be edited, however, you  may create a
header file for defining needed functions.

So far this is what I came up with, I just can't find out what 
    is wrong with my program. Help is appreciated.

main function: I can't edit the main function, however, you can create a header

```
#include "slow-prime.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int num;
    int nxt;enter code here
    int ret = EXIT_FAILURE;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("error: missing command line argument\n");
        goto ERROR;

    if (get_number(argv[1], &num)) {
            printf("error: %s not a number\n", argv[1]);
            goto ERROR;
        }

        next_prime(num, &nxt);
        printf("%d\n", nxt);
        ret = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    ERROR:
        return ret;
    }
}
```

needed functions are created in the slow-prime.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


// define true and false
#define true 1
#define false 0

// check whether the numer is prime or mnot
int isPrime(int num){
    if (num < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i <= num / i; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// get number
void get_number(char *argv[], int num) {
    num = atoi(argv[1]);
}

// loop through the numbers/ and pick the one

void next_prime(int num, int next){

    for(int i = 2; i < 80; i++){
        if (isPrime(i) == true){
            next = i;

            if (next > num) {
                return exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error Message:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Abw.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
void get_number(char *argv[], int num) {
```

and you are calling the function using:

```
if (get_number(argv[1], &num)) {
```

You are passing the wrong types for both arguments.

`argv[1]` is of type `char*`.
`&num` is of type `int*`.

I think you should to use:

```
void get_number(char *arg, int *num) {
```

and change the implementation slightly.

```
void get_number(char *arg, int *num) {
   *num = atoi(arg);
}
```

Also, given that `get_number` returns `void`, you cannot use it in the conditional of an `if` statement. You'll need to change its return type to something else, an `int` perhaps. In that case, using `atoi` might not be appropriate. `atoi` returns `0` when it cannot convert the string to an `int`. If `0` a valid value for you, then `atoi` is not a good choice. However, you can use `sprintf`for all cases.

If `0` is not a valid number, you can use:

```
int get_number(char *arg, int *num) {
   *num = atoi(arg);
   return *num;
}
```

If `0` is a valid number, you can use:

```
int get_number(char *arg, int *num) {
   return (sprintf(arg, "%d", num) == 1);
}
```

Comment: I have followed your comments and I was able to get rid off all of the errors except one: statement requires expression of scalar type ('void' invalid)           if (get_number(argv[1], &num)) {

Comment: @ab141, it's not clear to me when you expect the return value of `get_number` to evaluate to `false` and when to `true`.